# I need to show configurable products that are out of stock and block their purchase

Tags: configurable-product, stock-availability

I need to show configurable products that are out of stock and block their purchase.
To show out of stock. For normal products it works fine, but in the case of configurable products it just doesn't show them.
I managed to show all products. But the buy button is also available for products that are out of stock

Comment: Override plp and pdp page add flag to check is configurable type and  is salable false hide add to car button else show

Comment: can you attach a sample code?